# Scala - Mapping into a nested list and sorting on each level of list

Tags: scala, sorting, dictionary, nested

I have a function that returns a list of objects containing a list of child objects, where each child object can have children, and so on until an unknown level.

I want to be able to sort each level of the list until there's no more items to sort. I currently have a map that does this but only for the top level list items.

```
def nestedList(params): Future[List[CustomObject]] = {
    getNestedList(params).map {
    items =>
        items.sortBy(i => i.name)
    }
}
```

This returns a `Future[List[CustomObject]]` where custom object is `CustomObject(name, List[CustomObject]))`

How can I change this to return the entire list sorted?

Comment: Do you have `Future[List[List[CustomObject]]]`? Can you provide actual types?

Comment: This returns a `Future[List[CustomObject]]` where custom object is `CustomObject(name, List[CustomObject]))`

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose your `CustomObject` class looks like:

```
class CustomObject(val name: String, val children: List[CustomObject])
```

and you said there are unknown levels of children.
Then you can use the next function to sort your `List` of `CustomObject`s recursively:

```
def sortCustomObjects(a: List[CustomObject]): List[CustomObject] = {
  a.sortBy(_.name).map(co => new CustomObject(co.name, sortCustomObjects(co.children)))
}
```

**Please, note - I use recursion and it's not tail recursion - so you can get `StackOverflow` in large inputs.**

---

**UPD 1:**
You can also define `CustomeObject` as a `case class` and use `.copy` method in a more functional way:

```
case class CustomObject(name: String, children: List[CustomObject])

def sortCustomObjects(a: List[CustomObject]): List[CustomObject] = {
  a.sortBy(_.name).map(co => co.copy(children = sortCustomObjects(co.children)))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Say we have

```
val listsF = Future(List(List(1,3,54,6,3), List(9,7,8,4,3,3)))
```

then

```
listsF.map(_.map(_.sorted))
```

should do the job.

Comment: So I get an error saying `cannot resolve symbol sorted`. My root list is a list of objects which each have their own list that contain child objects. Could there be an issue because of this?

Comment: Sorry I explained my question poorly. A list of objects than can contain a list of child objects nested to an unknown number of levels.